# Find user records that haven't posted in 14 days

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm in private beta at the moment and I want to be able to get a list of people who haven't been active in the last week. I'm building this in codeigniter

model:

```
public function inactive_two_weeks($data) {
    $this->db->select('users.id, users.username, users.email, photo.created_on');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->join('photo', 'users.id = photo.userId');
    $this->db->where('photo.created_on NOT BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME('. $data .') AND FROM_UNIXTIME('. now().')');        
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->order_by('photo.created_on', 'desc');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

In my controller I have created the `$data` attribude which is just `strtotime('-1 week');`

What I'm getting at the moment seem to be everyone who has posted prior to last week, which is almost right. I just need it to only show those who haven't posted during the date range?

EDIT: Also I need to check to see if the user account is less than 1 week old

```
$this->db->where('users.joined <', $data);
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: may be you can use strtotime('last two weeks')

Comment: Checking the last activity using What?!! I think you better consider the last user's logout(or any similar recent event) and not when the photo is created!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join only with latest records, and then select only those with no records:

```
public function inactive_two_weeks($data) {
    $this->db->select('users.id, users.username, users.email, photo.created_on');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->join('photo', 'users.id = photo.userId AND photo.created_on BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME('. $data .') AND FROM_UNIXTIME('. now().')', 'left');
    $this->db->where('photo.created_on IS NULL');        
    $this->db->distinct();
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Hey Cthulhu, thanks for the quick response. This doesn't seem to return any restults?

Comment: @Tristan If account should be `less` then certain age, it's creation time must be `greater` then some border date, not less then.

Comment: i've written it as follows `$this->db->where('users.joined > FROM_UNIXTIME('. $oneweek .')');` but is still shows users who joined yesterday

Comment: Yes and those who joined yesterday are less then week old, aren't they? Maybe, you wanted only accounts `older` then 1 week? Then your initial condition (in the question) should work.

Comment: ha that did it' not sure what the initial problem was. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i use less than in where query

```
public function inactive_two_weeks($data) {
    $this->db->select('users.id, users.username, users.email, photo.created_on');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->join('photo', 'users.id = photo.userId');
    $this->db->where('photo.created_on <', 'datenow');// i edit the where part maybe i give you an idea
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->order_by('photo.created_on', 'desc');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```